# Why add-migration command is not creating migration? Not recognising packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

After installing the following packages:

`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0"`,
`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"` (-Pre)

When running the `add-migration "InitialCreate"` command, I get the following error:

`Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.` Though, if you look at the `.json` file below, you would see that the packages are matching, so this error message is contradicting to me.

This is my `project.json` file:

```
{
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `project.json` as shown below.

**Note :** need to include `"type": "platform"`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about this issue here : [**GitHub**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6883)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects in your solution. 
Use -projectname to select the right project, like this

add-migration InitialCreate -ProjectName mydbProject

Replace mydbProject with your project name